# secondary header from array value with datatables or html

Tags: javascript, php, html, datatables

In laravel, I'm using datatables to build a rather simple table structure from a php array and it's working perfectly but I want to see if there may be a way I can achieve a secondary header or a single row for one of my php values.

My PHP array is

```
data = [
    0=> array[
        "NUMBER" => "1"
        "GROUPNAME" => "first"
        "COLOR" => "red"
    ]
    1=> array[
        "NUMBER" => "1"
        "GROUPNAME" => "second"
        "COLOR" => "blue"
    ]
 ]
```

and so on.

So right now I have NUMBER as a column and data value, but I'm wondering if there's a simple way, using datatables, that I can group results by that NUMBER and let the number show as a secondary header, or even just a different row I can style to be more of a heading.

The code:

```
<table class="uk-table uk-table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Group</th>
            <th>Color</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($data as $row)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$row['NUMBER']}}</td>
            <td>{{$row['GROUPNAME']}}</td>
            <td>{{$row['COLOR']}}</td>

        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var dt = $('.report-table').DataTable({
        "pageLength": 50,
        "lengthMenu": [10,25,50],
        dom: 'Bflrtip',
        //'scrollX': true,
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ],

     });
</script>
```

Current result:

```
Number  | Group  |  Color
-------------------------
1         first      red
1         second     blue
1         third      green
2         first      red
2         second     blue
3         third      green
```

Desired result

```
Group  |  Color
---------------
Number 1
---------------
first     red
second    blue
third     green
----------------
Number 2
----------------
first     red
second    blue
----------------
Number 3
----------------
third     green
```

Comment: I made additional headers to have search bar for each of columns.
I placed tfoot into my html table element and then I run this jQuery code to move it up: $('thead').append($('tfoot tr'));

Comment: I'm thinking I'll need to alter the array loop structure as well though

Comment: I am not able to move it to the fiddle right now ( I will edit this comment later to fix that), but here is the link for one of my table http://adamtomas.eu/datatables/  .Use jQuery I mentioned in previous comment to check what I ment.